# Elementary results on Stanley-Reisner rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, soft-question, simplicial-complex

**Context:** I am looking for topics for an final exam talk of a commutative algebra course.

I have come across the notion of Stanley-Reisner rings in the Miller and Sturmfels' book *Combinatorial Commutative Algebra* and Stanley's book *Combinatorics and Commutative Algebra*.

> What are some somewhat self-contained applications of Stanley-Reisner rings to the study of simplicial complexes?

I am aware that, for example, they were used by Stanley to prove the Upper Bound Conjecture for simplicial spheres. The proof found in Stanley's book however contains a fair amount of non-trivial results. For example, a result by Hatcher that describes a necessary and sufficient topological condition for a Stanley-Reisner ring $k[\Delta]$ to be Cohen-Macaulay is used.

**Edit:** by "somewhat self-contained" I mean for the prerequisites to be no more than an elementary course in commutative algebra (we have covered most of the topics in Atiyah-Macdonald) and algebraic/simplicial topology.

Comment: I think this is at best bordering on being elementary. The point (or one of the points) of the SR ring of an abstract simplicial complex is to use methods from homological algebra (including the Hilbert series), and they are in general not elementary. The other side of this is lattices of square free monomial ideals, and they are more accessible if you have dealt with Atiyah-Macdonald. Perhaps that is a good starting point: find the order-reversing bijection between abstract simplicial complexes and square-free monomial ideals, by using the natural ordering on each side.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on your last sentence (if you want, making the comment into an answer)? In Miller and Sturmfels' book, Theorem 1.7 they state the bijective correspondence and a description of the Stanley-Reisner ideals in terms of intersection of prime monomial ideals and the proof says  "By definition, the set of squarefree monomials that have nonzero images in the Stanley–Reisner ring $S/I_\Delta$ is precisely $\{x^\sigma \mid  \sigma \in \Delta\}$. This shows that the map $\Delta \rightsquigarrow I_\Delta$ is bijective".

Comment: If $\Delta$ is an abstract simplicial complex, then $I_\Delta = (x^\sigma \mid \sigma \notin \Delta)$ is the associated square-free monomial ideal. In the reverse direction, given any such ideal $I \subset k[x_1, ..., x_n]$, then generate an abstract simplical complex by the index support sets of the monomials not in $I$ (you can find notation and everything in Miller-Sturmfels). This is the (bijective) Stanley-Reisner correspondence. One can place partial orders of divisibility on the the monomial ideal, and of inclusion on the complex, which are "opposite" of eachother.